# .net core angular 4 application jquery grid 'document is not defined' ERROR --

Tags: jquery, json, angular, npm, asp.net-core

need some help with this scenario.

Trying to use a jquery based grid called gijgo in .net core angular application. Before starting off I studied some of the available examples on the Internet, mostly mvc5. I have tried my bit by doing adding npm package, writing some of the markup. Right now, as I launch the app. I get an error which mostly says - **document is not defined**. I am guessing this has something to do with adding+referencing the jquery lib. incorrectly in my app. I am not sure, because I am very new to angular applications. Here's some of the code I did::

product.component html --

```
    <div class="h2">Products</div>
<br />


<div id="productSection">
    <div class="gj-margin-top-10">
        <table id="grid">

        </table>
    </div> 
</div>
```

product.component TS --

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef, OnDestroy, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common';
import { Credentials } from '../../shared/models/credentials.interface';
import { CommonFunctionsService } from "../../shared/services/common.functions.service";
import { AppService } from "../../shared/services/AppService";
import { UserStore, IUserStore } from "../../shared/models/store.interface";
import { IStandardResponse } from "../../shared/models/standardresponse.interface";
import * as $ from 'jquery';


@Component({
    selector: 'products',
    templateUrl: './product.component.html'

})

export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy
{
    constructor(private router: Router, private common: CommonFunctionsService, private appSrvc: AppService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // subscribe to router event
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var grid = $('#grid').grid({      **<-------- error here property grid does not exist on type jquery<HtmlElement>**
                primaryKey: 'ProdID',
                dataSource: '/Home/GetStoreProducts',
                columns: [
                    { field: 'ProdID', hidden: true },
                    { field: 'Name', sortable: true },
                    { field: 'Price', sortable: true },
                    {
                        width: 64,
                        tmpl: '<span class="material-icons gj-cursor-pointer">View Details</span>',
                        align: 'center',
                        events: { 'click': ProductDetails }
                    },
                    {
                        width: 64,
                        tmpl: '<span class="material-icons gj-cursor-pointer">Edit</span>',
                        align: 'center',
                        events: { 'click': Edit }
                    }
                ],
                pager: { limit: 10 }
            });
        });

    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // prevent memory leak by unsubscribing

    }
}
```

bower.json --

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "jquery": "2.2.0",
    "gijgo": "1.7.3",
    "jquery-validation": "1.14.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": ">= 1.7.2"
  }
}
```

and package.json --

```
{
  "name": "CoreRIA_Web",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3"
  }
}
```

To solve this problems I tried some other trial error approaches. Like writing the jquery code in the html file itself inside a script section,
adding **declare var $:any** in the TS component code etc. None did the trick, the same error shows up. What is to be done? How to do resolve this? Can you please show me a way how to correctly go about this? Look forward to some guidance,
Thanks so much,

Comment: basically this is what my page shows as error now when I launch it ----


NodeInvocationException: document is not defined
ReferenceError: document is not defined
at DefaultDomRenderer2.module.exports.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (E:\REPRIMX\CoreRedux.Web\CoreRIA.Web\CoreRIA.Web\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:28722:72)
at BaseAnimationRenderer.selectRootElement (E:\REPRIMX\CoreRedux.Web\CoreRIA.Web\CoreRIA.Web\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:3792:106)
at createElement (E:\REPRIMX\CoreRedux.Web\CoreRIA.Web\CoreRIA.Web\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:20127:23)
at  .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have an example where this is already configured at http://gijgo.com/grid/demos/angular-6

Answer (score 0):

For using jquery correctly you should install types for that.

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

After installing types, change your jquery import to this:

```
import 'jquery'
```

Now you should wrap your `$(something)` calls with an any type. Like this:

```
(<any>$(document)).ready(function ()...
```

or

```
(<any>$('#grid')).grid(...
```

Comment: hi Gregor,
I've tried the modifications you suggested. added the <any> explicit casts. but same error persists. red error weeblies over .grid, ProductDetails, Edit. one thing to note here, if I move this code to the html component inside script tag, these red error signs go away even though the console error still remains the same and the page fails to load. what next,  ?  thanks,

Comment: basically this is what my page shows as error now when I launch it --


NodeInvocationException: document is not defined
ReferenceError: document is not defined
at DefaultDomRenderer2.module.exports.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (E:\REPRIMX\CoreRedux.Web\CoreRIA.Web\CoreRIA.Web\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:28722:72)
at BaseAnimationRenderer.selectRootElement (E:\REPRIMX\CoreRedux.Web\CoreRIA.Web\CoreRIA.Web\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:3792:106)
at createElement (E:\REPRIMX\CoreRedux.Web\CoreRIA.Web\CoreRIA.Web\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:20127:23)
at  .......